# Transforming an XML file that contains logical operators in attribute values..?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to create an XSLT transformation on an XML file that has logical operators as attribute values. **My question is**, is it super complicated to create this XSLT transformation or do I have to code some kind of a "processor" from scratch that understands these logical operators in my attributes?

Here's an example of how I would want it to work:

I have an example XML that looks like this:

```
<book>
  <chapter condition="A and B">Chapter 1</chapter>
  <chapter condition="not B">Chapter 2</chapter>
  <chapter condition="A or D">Chapter 3</chapter>
  <chapter condition="not C">Chapter 4</chapter>
  <chapter condition="D and (B or C)">Chapter 5</chapter> 
  <chapter condition="D">Chapter 6</chapter> 
</book>
```

Then I have a list of values "**Values = [B, D]**", and I would like to loop through this list and remove those chapters that do not "match" the values in this list.

So considering these values: **[B, D]**, the output XML after the transformation would look like this:

```
<book>
  #This would get removed, seeing as it requires both A and B values.
  <chapter condition="A and B">Chapter 1</chapter> 

  #This would also get removed, seeing as the attribute is "not B", so 
  if B value is present, it gets removed.
  <chapter condition="not B">Chapter 2</chapter>

  #This chapter would stay, the value D is present.
  <chapter condition="A or D">Chapter 3</chapter> 

  #This chapter would also stay, as the value C is not in our list.
  <chapter condition="not C">Chapter 4</chapter> 

  #In this case this chapter would stay, seeing as we have value D and B. 
  <chapter condition="D and (B or C)">Chapter 5</chapter> 

  #This chapter would stay, as value D is present in our list.
  <chapter condition="D">Chapter 6</chapter> 
</book>
```

What would be the smartest way to go about achieving this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what kind of language you have inside of the conditions and what kind of values you have in terms of XSLT/XPath (what is `Values = [B, D]` in terms of XSLT/XPath?) If you want to rely on XPath then the expressions should use XPath syntax e.g. with declared variables `A` to `D` as `xs:boolean` values and referenced as e.g `$A and $B`, that way you might be able to use XSLT 3's `xsl:evaluate` or perhaps a proprietary extension for dynamic XPath evaluation.

Comment: Good point. This is just something I stumbled over and I'm honestly quite confused as to how this works. I think the language inside the attributes is supposed to be Java(?) as far as I'm aware.I was under the assumption that the logical operators was something that an XSLT transformation would "understand". I'm very comfortable with Python, not sure if there's a way to do in collaboration with Python/XSLT/Xpath?

Comment: If you're using Python (i.e. libxslt), you can take advantage of the XSLT `dyn:evaluate()` extension function. But you must first transform the expressions into XPath syntax: replace the true propositions with `true()` or `1` and change `not P` to `not(P)`. The former is relatively easy, the latter less so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can adapt the syntax to use the XPath `not()` function/operator and we can assume that all upper-case sequences of letters that are in your list represent the boolean value true and any not represented the boolean value false then you can use dynamic XPath evaluation with `xsl:evaluate` in XSLT 3 on an expression created from your condition:

So the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <chapter condition="A and B">Chapter 1</chapter>
    <chapter condition="not(B)">Chapter 2</chapter>
    <chapter condition="A or D">Chapter 3</chapter>
    <chapter condition="not(C)">Chapter 4</chapter>
    <chapter condition="D and (B or C)">Chapter 5</chapter> 
    <chapter condition="D">Chapter 6</chapter> 
</book>
```

with Saxon 9.7 or later PE or EE or any other XSLT 3 processor supporting `xsl:evaluate` could be transformed with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="true-values" as="xs:string*" select="'B', 'D'"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:substitute-variables" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="expression" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="substituted-expression" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string($expression, '\p{Lu}+')" mode="substitution"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="string-join($substituted-expression)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="*:match[not(. = $true-values)]" mode="substitution">
        <xsl:text>false()</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:match[. = $true-values]" mode="substitution">
        <xsl:text>true()</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:evaluate-condition" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="expression" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:evaluate xpath="$expression"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="chapter[@condition and not(mf:evaluate-condition(mf:substitute-variables(@condition)))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to

```
<book>


    <chapter condition="A or D">Chapter 3</chapter>
    <chapter condition="not(C)">Chapter 4</chapter>
    <chapter condition="D and (B or C)">Chapter 5</chapter> 
    <chapter condition="D">Chapter 6</chapter> 
</book>
```

Assuming XSLT with support for the XPath 3.1 `transform` function you could avoid the use of `xsl:evaluate` (which is only available in the commercial versions of Saxon 9 while `transform` is supported in the open-source HE of 9.8 and later versions) and construct a stylesheet on the fly that contains the necessary conditions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="true-values" as="xs:string*" select="'B', 'D'"/>

    <xsl:namespace-alias  stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:substitute-variables" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="expression" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="substituted-expression" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string($expression, '\p{Lu}+')" mode="substitution"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="string-join($substituted-expression)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="*:match[not(. = $true-values)]" mode="substitution">
        <xsl:text>false()</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:match[. = $true-values]" mode="substitution">
        <xsl:text>true()</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode name="template" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:variable name="stylesheet">
        <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
            <axsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>         
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//chapter[@condition]" mode="template"/>
        </axsl:stylesheet>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="chapter[@condition]" mode="template">
        <axsl:template match="chapter[@condition = '{@condition}']">
            <axsl:if test="{mf:substitute-variables(@condition)}">
                <axsl:next-match/>
            </axsl:if>
        </axsl:template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:sequence 
            select="transform(
                      map {
                        'source-node' : .,
                        'stylesheet-node' : $stylesheet
                      }
                    )?output"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Still assumes the `not` operator is used in XPath style and some textual conversion of "variable" names (e.g. 'A', 'B') to boolean values is possible with regular expressions. Online example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nf.

As for applying it to more elements, I would then suggest to declare a global parameter where you provide the XPath expression to select those and use it in the code generating the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="true-values" as="xs:string*" select="'B', 'D', 'YES'"/>

    <xsl:param name="elements-to-be-transformed" select="//chapter[@condition], //chapter/title[@condition]"/>

    <xsl:namespace-alias  stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:substitute-variables" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="expression" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="substituted-expression" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string($expression, '\p{Lu}+')" mode="substitution"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="string-join($substituted-expression)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="*:match[not(. = $true-values)]" mode="substitution">
        <xsl:text>false()</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:match[. = $true-values]" mode="substitution">
        <xsl:text>true()</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode name="template" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:variable name="stylesheet">
        <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
            <axsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>         
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$elements-to-be-transformed" mode="template"/>
        </axsl:stylesheet>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="*[@condition]" mode="template">
        <axsl:template match="{node-name()}[@condition = '{@condition}']">
            <axsl:if test="{mf:substitute-variables(@condition)}">
                <axsl:next-match/>
            </axsl:if>
        </axsl:template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:sequence 
            select="transform(
                      map {
                        'source-node' : .,
                        'stylesheet-node' : $stylesheet
                      }
                    )?output"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nf/1.

Comment: Hey again Martin. Requesting one more thing in addition to this. What should I change in the current Regex '[\p{L}_][\p{L}_0-9]*' so that it could accept strings that also start with a number? As of right now it doesn't recognize the string if it's for example "123Variable", thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried some regular expression tutorial? If the current expression `[\p{L}_][\p{L}_0-9]*` describes a sequence starting with a single letter or underscore `[\p{L}_]` followed by optional letters, digits or underscores `[\p{L}_0-9]*` it seems clear you want to drop the first part and make the second obligatory: `[\p{L}_0-9]+`. Be aware that XPath has number literals (e.g. `12`) that would match `[\p{L}_0-9]+`, thus if your conditions would want to also make numerical checks on the XPath side (e.g. `MyVar = 2`) and not only the boolean checks you had so far you will run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Helpful as always.